# Finding the common value on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Having a bit of an issue creating this algorithm hoping someone can help. I am trying to see what laptops are most commonly being damaged in accordance to the teacher.

Basically what I am trying to do is, I am trying to figure out what laptops that are assigned to a specific teacher are being damaged the most. I work at a school and I want to see if theres a pattern to the laptops that are damaged.

I want to go from an overall data set of ALL teachers and ALL incidents, to then having a tally count of each teachers, and finally to the laptop and teacher that is most commonly being repaired

Example Teacher1 has the laptop with the asset tag 1232 that pops up twice. I want the most common laptop that is assigned to the teacher to pop up in the **Most Common** column.

[a test sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/lennoxk12.org/spreadsheets/d/1A1NoxMgkYapGWZ8ch1K0DTlpDLlo7nwj8k7Bn5g0LeQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Currently trying out a pivot table. Trying to figure out how to get the common value for each teacher.

Comment: Gave the it a try and it wasn't working out. Although I am now thinking of using a pivot table to organize my data on my spreadsheet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a query like this

```
=query(A:E,"select C,count(C) where A='"&G2&"' group by C order by count(C) desc limit 1 label C '',count(C) ''")
```

Where the asset tag is in column C and the teacher name is in G2.

[image]

Comment: Just gave it a go and it worked! This is going to be such a great help to me! Thank you!

Comment: Great - so you have a few options now.